# Node.js dgram UDP failing when sending many packets

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp

I am creating a node application that will send UDP packets to another machine. Everything appears to work fine when packets are sent about 100/second. When that number gets higher 500/second the packets stop sending. I don't think they are being droped as Wireshark does not show them leaving my computer.

```
const dgram = require("dgram");

var sent = 0;
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

function sendCommand(text){

    // Put command into a buffer
    var buffer = new Buffer(text);

    // Send the command
    server.send(buffer, 0, buffer.length, 12345, 19.5.6.45, (err) => {
        sent++;
    });

}
```

The sendCommand() function is what is called internally. Like I said at 100 calls per second no problem. When it gets higher it just stops working.

The "sent" var stops incrementing so this leads me to think node dgram is faulty and server.send() is not firing correctly. It doesn't seem to recover unless I restart the program.

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow, I apologise if I did anything wrong.

Edit:

Here is where the function is firing from.

```
// Loop through the channels
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

    // Check if the channel is locked
    if (!toBool(data.locks[i])) {

        // Send the UDP command
        sendCommand(ids[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: can you show the code responsible to generate the 500 qps ?

Comment: Sure! I added where the function is firing from. It is inside a for loop. I am pretty sure the function is running because I had a counter inside sendCommand() and it was incrementing.

Comment: do you mean this code is within the same process then the one handling the udp connections ?

Comment: The function is defined first, along with the require dgram. Further down the script is where the for loop is.

Comment: This is really weird. Sometimes it allows it to go higher and sometimes it just stops. It never recovers. I was reading some other threads, I am wondering if this is some kind of internal overflow for node. Could be a bug with dgram? Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Found the issue. The DNS lookup in the dgram module was failing. I edited the source and bingo it works!